# Past perfect vs. simple past

Tags: verbs, tenses, formality

What verb tense must I use in the following sentences? I'm describing my work experience in casual speech.

> 1. I had been working at Apple for five years. [I imply that I worked there in the past]
> 2. I've worked at Google for four years. [I imply that I've worked there till now]
> 3. Now I'm unemployed and looking for a job at McDonald's.

Are these three sentences correct? Maybe in the first one I must use the past simple tense?

Comment: Goolge? 1. is possible if you continue the sentence "I had been working at Apple for five years when Microsoft offered me a position I couldn't refuse" 2. Is OK but I would understand it to mean you are currently working there and 3. is fine. I'm not 100% convinced with the preposition "at" in 1. and 2.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks! I've google it and i've found at least 2 different option. And thanks for the prepositions.So, how to say what I imply in the best way? 1. I worked in Apple for 5 years. 2. ??? 3.Ok).

Comment: First, you need to correct the spelling of **Goolge** and **tences** in your title. Second, in casual speech they are all perfectly fine, but for 1. It's probably best to use the past simple tense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say,

> I worked at apple for five years. This implies that you worked there and you no longer work there. You can expand it a bit more to be more precise. *I worked at apple for five years from 2001 to 2005.*
>
> If you are still employed there, then it is better to use the perfect form, because there's a connection between your past work experience and what you are currently doing. So the second sentence is correct.
>
> The past perfect can only be used when you want to talk about two things that happened in the past but you want to say that one of the actions/things happened before the other one. In this case that doesn't seem like the case. So, it's better to avoid the first example.